# SceneKit animate node along path

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit

I have a box node

```
_boxNode = [SCNNode node];
_boxNode.geometry = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:1 height:1 length:1 chamferRadius:0];
_boxNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -2);
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:_boxNode];
```

I have a path

```
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(-2, -2, 4, 4), nil);
```

I want to have my box travel along my path once.

How do I do this in SceneKit?

I'd like to make a method that would look like

```
[_boxNode runAction:[SCNAction moveAlongPath:path forDuration:duration]];
```

Comment: What's stopping you from running a search?  I have seen a similar topic before.

Comment: I've done this before with a CAKeyAnimation. SceneKit has no built in API to travel along a path. My working creations are bulky and overcomplicated at best. So I'm wondering if someone has a simple solution.

Comment: doesn't adding that CoreAnimation animation to the node work?

Comment: It does not. At least it said it wasn't supported when I tried.. Which was yesterday..

Comment: Scenekit really needs support for Splines... A way to do it by hand is build the path in a 3D software, then interpolate the position between the points yourself. That's how I usually do it.

Comment: No kidding, can we make like a feature request somewhere?

Comment: Check out this answer. Hopefully it's helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24332672/885189

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I came across that question as well and I wrote a little playground. The animation works well. One thing needs to be done. The distance between every point has to be calculated so that time can be scaled to get a smooth animation. Just copy & paste the code into a playground. The code is in Swift 3.

Here is my solution (the BezierPath extension is not from me, found it here):

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let animationDuration = 0.1

public extension UIBezierPath {

    var elements: [PathElement] {
        var pathElements = [PathElement]()
        withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &pathElements) { elementsPointer in
            cgPath.apply(info: elementsPointer) { (userInfo, nextElementPointer) in
                let nextElement = PathElement(element: nextElementPointer.pointee)
                let elementsPointer = userInfo!.assumingMemoryBound(to: [PathElement].self)
                elementsPointer.pointee.append(nextElement)
            }
        }
        return pathElements
    }
}

public enum PathElement {

    case moveToPoint(CGPoint)
    case addLineToPoint(CGPoint)
    case addQuadCurveToPoint(CGPoint, CGPoint)
    case addCurveToPoint(CGPoint, CGPoint, CGPoint)
    case closeSubpath

    init(element: CGPathElement) {
        switch element.type {
        case .moveToPoint: self = .moveToPoint(element.points[0])
        case .addLineToPoint: self = .addLineToPoint(element.points[0])
        case .addQuadCurveToPoint: self = .addQuadCurveToPoint(element.points[0], element.points[1])
        case .addCurveToPoint: self = .addCurveToPoint(element.points[0], element.points[1], element.points[2])
        case .closeSubpath: self = .closeSubpath
        }
    }
}

public extension SCNAction {

    class func moveAlong(path: UIBezierPath) -> SCNAction {

        let points = path.elements
        var actions = [SCNAction]()

        for point in points {

            switch point {
            case .moveToPoint(let a):
                let moveAction = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(a.x, a.y, 0), duration: animationDuration)
                actions.append(moveAction)
                break

            case .addCurveToPoint(let a, let b, let c):
                let moveAction1 = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(a.x, a.y, 0), duration: animationDuration)
                let moveAction2 = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(b.x, b.y, 0), duration: animationDuration)
                let moveAction3 = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(c.x, c.y, 0), duration: animationDuration)
                actions.append(moveAction1)
                actions.append(moveAction2)
                actions.append(moveAction3)
                break

            case .addLineToPoint(let a):
                let moveAction = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(a.x, a.y, 0), duration: animationDuration)
                actions.append(moveAction)
                break

            case .addQuadCurveToPoint(let a, let b):
                let moveAction1 = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(a.x, a.y, 0), duration: animationDuration)
                let moveAction2 = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(b.x, b.y, 0), duration: animationDuration)
                actions.append(moveAction1)
                actions.append(moveAction2)
                break

            default:
                let moveAction = SCNAction.move(to: SCNVector3(0, 0, 0), duration: animationDuration)
                actions.append(moveAction)
                break
            }   
        }
        return SCNAction.sequence(actions)
    }
}



let scnView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

let scene = SCNScene()
scnView.scene = scene

let light = SCNLight()
light.type = .ambient
let lightNode = SCNNode()
lightNode.light = light
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

let camera = SCNCamera()
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = camera
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(0,0,10)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

let box = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
boxNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

let path1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: 2, height: 2), cornerRadius: 1)

let moveAction = SCNAction.moveAlong(path: path1)
let repeatAction = SCNAction.repeatForever(moveAction)
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = Double(path1.elements.count) * animationDuration
boxNode.runAction(repeatAction)
SCNTransaction.commit()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = scnView
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I made a quick tutorial on how to create a NURBS path in blender, and then have an object to follow it (in this case the ship that comes with the default new project code in Xcode.

You can also find this under my [gist here](https://gist.github.com/Farini/ede665cab4e736480d4f399fbb4ca4f3)

**Things to consider**

1. Move.: You need the points in space [SCNVector]
2. Point.: One object to move ahead, so the original object (ship) can follow, respecting the orientation of the path.
3. The boxes are just for illustration of the path. They can be removed
4. See how to export NURBS in `RoutePath`
5. This is an XCode project that comes when you start a new project -> game -> Swift -> SceneKit

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {

       super.viewDidLoad()

       // create a new scene
       let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

       // create and add a camera to the scene
       let cameraNode = SCNNode()
       cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
       scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

       // place the camera
       cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -10)

       // create and add a light to the scene
       let lightNode = SCNNode()
       lightNode.light = SCNLight()
       lightNode.light!.type = .omni
       lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
       scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

       // create and add an ambient light to the scene
       let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
       ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
       ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
       ambientLightNode.light!.color = NSColor.darkGray
       scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

       // MARK: - Path (Orientation)

       // Orientation node: Ahead of the ship, the orientation node is used to
       // maintain the ship's orientation (rotating the ship according to path's next point)
       let orientationNode = SCNNode()
       scene.rootNode.addChildNode(orientationNode)

       // MARK: - Path (Ship)

       // retrieve the ship node
       let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!
       ship.scale = SCNVector3(0.15, 0.15, 0.15)

       // Get the path you want to follow
       var pathToFollow:[SCNVector3] = RoutePath.decodePath()

       // Set the ship to start at the path's first point
       ship.position = pathToFollow.first!

       // Constraint ship to look at orientationNode
       let shipLook = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: orientationNode)
       shipLook.localFront = SCNVector3(0, 0, 1)
       shipLook.worldUp = SCNVector3(0, 1, 0)
       shipLook.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
       ship.constraints = [shipLook]

       // Camera Constraints (Following ship)
       let look = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: ship)
       let follow = SCNDistanceConstraint(target: ship)
       follow.minimumDistance = 3
       follow.maximumDistance = 6
       cameraNode.constraints = [look, follow]

       // MARK: - Actions

       // Ship's actions
       var shipActions:[SCNAction] = []

       // Actions for the orientation node
       var orientationActions:[SCNAction] = []

       // Populate Path Animations
       while !pathToFollow.isEmpty {

           pathToFollow.remove(at: 0)
           if let next = pathToFollow.first {

               let act = SCNAction.move(to: next, duration: 0.8)

               if pathToFollow.count > 1 {
                   let dest = pathToFollow[1]
                   let oriact = SCNAction.move(to: dest, duration: 0.8)
                   orientationActions.append(oriact)
               }

               shipActions.append(act)

               // add box
               let box = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
               let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
               boxNode.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.blue
               boxNode.position = SCNVector3(Double(next.x), Double(next.y + 0.4), Double(next.z))
               scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
           }
       }

       // Animate Orientation node
       let oriSequence = SCNAction.sequence(orientationActions)
       orientationNode.runAction(oriSequence)

       // Animate Ship node
       let sequence = SCNAction.sequence(shipActions)
       ship.runAction(sequence) {
           print("Ship finished sequence")
       }

       // MARK: - View Setup

       // retrieve the SCNView
       let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

       // set the scene to the view
       scnView.scene = scene

       // show statistics such as fps and timing information
       scnView.showsStatistics = true

       // configure the view
       scnView.backgroundColor = NSColor.black

   }
   ```

For the Path Object to follow:

This path was made in blender, with a Nurbs Path. Then it was exported as `.obj` file.

OPTIONS - IMPORTANT
When exporting, mark the following options

1. 'curves as NURBS'
2. 'keep vertex order'

Open the `.obj` file in text editor and copy the vertex positions, as you see in the rawPath String

```
struct RoutePath {

/// Transforms the `rawPath` into an array of `SCNVector3`
static func decodePath() -> [SCNVector3] {
    
    let whole = rawPath.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    print("\nWhole:\n\(whole.count)")
    
    var vectors:[SCNVector3] = []
    
    for line in whole {
        
        let vectorParts = line.components(separatedBy: " ")
        if let x = Double(vectorParts[1]),
           let y = Double(vectorParts[2]),
           let z = Double(vectorParts[3]) {
            
            let vector = SCNVector3(x, y, z)
            print("Vector: \(vector)")
            
            vectors.append(vector)
        }
    }
    
    return vectors
}

static var rawPath:String {
    """
    v 26.893915 -4.884228 49.957905
    v 26.893915 -4.884228 48.957905
    v 26.893915 -4.884228 47.957905
    v 26.901930 -4.884228 46.617016
    v 26.901930 -4.884228 45.617016
    v 26.901930 -4.884228 44.617016
    v 26.901930 -4.884228 43.617016
    v 26.901930 -4.884228 42.617016
    v 26.901930 -4.884228 41.617016
    v 26.901930 -4.884228 40.617016
    v 26.901930 -4.884228 39.617016
    v 26.391232 -4.884228 38.617016
    v 25.574114 -4.884228 37.617016
    v 25.046391 -4.884228 36.617016
    v 24.552715 -4.884228 35.617016
    v 24.365459 -4.884228 34.617016
    v 24.365459 -4.884228 33.617016
    v 24.314390 -4.884228 32.617016
    v 24.212250 -4.884228 31.617016
    v 24.110109 -4.884228 30.617016
    v 23.995176 -4.884228 29.617016
    v 23.913080 -4.884228 28.617016
    v 23.814566 -4.884228 27.617016
    v 24.356396 -4.884228 26.978235
    v 25.356396 -4.884228 26.978235
    v 26.356396 -4.884228 26.978235
    v 27.356396 -4.736906 26.978235
    v 28.356396 -4.549107 26.978235
    v 29.356396 -4.549107 26.978235
    """
    }
}
```