# Moving a node along a path in SceneKit

Tags: scenekit, uibezierpath, bezier

I have a bezier path, made from QuadCurves, so it's smooth.

Now I would like to move a plane along that path, not necessarily animate it, but just move the node to maybe the centre of the path.

I have tried everything that I could find and I couldn't get the plane moving.

How do I do this? Should I use CGPaths and CAKeyFrameAnimation? If so, how?

Comment: technical nit: those are not two different things. If it moves from moment to moment, that *is* animation.

Comment: Have you had a look at my answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/40596990/4089350