# Arrange SCNNodes in Circle

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, virtual-reality

I'm creating multiple nodes automatically and I want to arrange them around me, because at the moment I'm just increasing of 0.1 the current X location.

```
capsuleNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = imageView
capsuleNode.position = SCNVector3(self.counterX, self.counterY, self.counterZ)
capsuleNode.name = topic.name
self.sceneLocationView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(capsuleNode)
self.counterX += 0.1
```

So the question is, how can I have all of them around me instead of just in one line?

Did someone of you have some math function for this? Thank you!

Comment: I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064816/scenekit-animate-node-along-path/40596990#40596990 which feels like something you could use to get the positions for the circle.. Basically you create a circle with bezier path and then you can select certain points where you want to place them

Comment: Did you check my ARKIT answer ?

Comment: I'm going to try both of the answers

Comment: @PietroMessineo Just copy paste the `func arrangeNode(nodes:[SCNNode])` pass your array you're done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code (macOS version) to test it:

```
import SceneKit

class GameViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = SCNScene()
        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
        scnView.scene = scene
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
        scnView.backgroundColor = NSColor.black

        for i in 1...12 {  // HERE ARE 12 SPHERES

            let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 1))
            sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)

            // ROTATE ABOUT THIS OFFSET PIVOT POINT
            sphereNode.simdPivot.columns.3.x = 5
            sphereNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor(calibratedHue: CGFloat(i)/12, 
                                                                              saturation: 1, 
                                                                              brightness: 1,                
                                                                                   alpha: 1)

            // ROTATE ABOUT Y AXIS (STEP is 30 DEGREES EXPRESSED IN RADIANS)
            sphereNode.rotation = SCNVector4(0, 1, 0, (-CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(i))/6)
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

> P.S. Here's a code for creating 90 spheres:

```
for i in 1...90 {

    let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.1))
    sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
    sphereNode.simdPivot.columns.3.x = 5
    sphereNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor(calibratedHue: CGFloat(i)/90, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
    sphereNode.rotation = SCNVector4(0, 1, 0, (-CGFloat.pi * (CGFloat(i))/6)/7.5)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have a question now, if I have more than 12 elements, which parameters I need to modify? For example I have 90 elements to display around me

Comment: Change `for-in` loop to `1...90`. And degree: ` sphereNode.rotation = SCNVector4(0, 1, 0, N`. N must be equal to 4 degrees (convert it in Radians).

Comment: I haven't got it, N could be just: (-CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(i))/(90/2) ?

Comment: Look at the picture. Work with a numerator and denominator)))

Answer (score 1):

You need some math here

**How I prepare the circle nodes**

```
    var nodes = [SCNNode]()
    for i in  1...20 {
        let node = createSphereNode(withRadius: 0.05, color: .yellow)
        nodes.append(node)
        node.position = SCNVector3(0,0,-1 * 1 / i)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        self.arrangeNode(nodes: nodes)
    }


   func createSphereNode(withRadius radius: CGFloat, color: UIColor) -> SCNNode {
        let geometry = SCNSphere(radius: radius)
        geometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = color
        let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
        return sphereNode
   }
```

**Math behind arrange the view into circle**

```
func arrangeNode(nodes:[SCNNode]) {

        let radius:CGFloat = 1;

        let angleStep = 2.0 * CGFloat.pi / CGFloat(nodes.count)

        var count:Int = 0

        for node in nodes {
            let xPos:CGFloat = CGFloat(self.sceneView.pointOfView?.position.x ?? 0) + CGFloat(cosf(Float(angleStep) * Float(count))) * (radius - 0)
            let zPos:CGFloat = CGFloat(self.sceneView.pointOfView?.position.z ?? 0) + CGFloat(sinf(Float(angleStep) * Float(count))) * (radius - 0)

            node.position = SCNVector3(xPos, 0, zPos)

            count = count + 1
        }


    }
```

Note: In third image I have set.

```
            let xPos:CGFloat =  -1 + CGFloat(cosf(Float(angleStep) * Float(count))) * (radius - 0)
            let zPos:CGFloat = -1 + CGFloat(sinf(Float(angleStep) * Float(count))) * (radius - 0)
```

That means if you need view around the camera then

use `CGFloat(self.sceneView.pointOfView?.position.x ?? 0)` or at the random place then provide the value

Output

[image]
[image]

[image]