# SCNAction versus translation from matrix?

Tags: ios, swift

If I want to move and rotate a SCNPyramid around a SCNBox and have it keep resetting would I use multiple SCNActions or a matrix translation? If I'm suppose to use a translation can someone post a link to help me out?

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320456/revolve-a-scnode-object-in-the-3d-space-using-scenekit

Comment: Thank you it helped me out ^!